# Going back a page manually messes things up

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem with a website I'm making for a friend of mine.

Basically the home page is a div with an image in it, and a menu bar with links in the middle of it. Using jquery I prevent the default action of clicking on a link, after that the menu bar slides up, the pressed link becomes active and at the same time the image fades out. After that you get redirected to the selected page. This works, it's a smooth transition and you don't even really notice the page transition. The problem is, if you are redirected to the page, and press the browsers back button, you will return to the homepage but the image will still be disappeared, the menu bar will be in top and the previous link will still have the class "active".

So basically it's like you go back to the homepage, but in a state wherein the page has already executed the jQuery. I don't want this, it just has to be the same as if you would refresh the page. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.nav_item a').click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#menu").on('click', '.nav_item', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('nav_item_active');
        $("#menu").css('top','-10px');
        $("#menu").css('background','rgba(89, 89, 89, 0)');
        $("#background_image").css('opacity','0');
        var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');

        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location = href;
        }, 1300);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: We're gonna need to see your code to be able to help you with this.  Just a description of it is not enough.  Also, are you using "history.pushState()` by chance?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, editing the post with my code now

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found the answer. I had to add `onunload=""` to body tag.

```
<body onunload="">
```